# Firebase rewrites to functions does not intercept root url requests

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

i have the following firebase hosting configuration in `firebase.json`

```
    {
        "target": "app",
        "public": "dist/browser",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [{
                "source": "/app3/**",
                "destination": "/app3/index.html"
            },
            {
                "source": "/app2/**",
                "function": "serveApp2"
            },
            {
                "source": "**",
                "function": "serveApp1"
            }
        ]
    }
```

those fireabse functions are actually serving Angular universal apps

when i visit the domain [https://example.com/ or https://example.com/app2] the functions doesnt run at all as i can see the function logs. nothing gets printed

but when i visit an internal path of an app [ex. https://example.com/some-path or https://example.com/app2/some-path] then i get the logs and also the ssr works fine

why firebase hosting not intercepting root url requests ??

please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741144/base-url-hosting-doesnt-trigger-cloud-functions

Comment: Check my question/answer it worked for me

Comment: @KlausGreinerFiorini i alredy figured it out. anyways u get an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add fields that specifically catch the root node as well - This is because `"/**"` does not wild card on `""` but rather `"/"`

You can get around this by having `"/app2**"`redirect to serveApp2

Comment: i didnt get time to open my laptop. sorry for the late reply. let my see it